# Does the RubyZip library support --fix option

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, zip, rubyzip

In my code, I'm using the RubyZip library to create an archive

```
Zip::File.open("1.zip", true) do |zf|
    Dir[File.join(Dir.pwd, '**', '**')].each do |f| 
        zf.add(f, f) 
    end
end
```

and then prepend a file with cat to the archive. After I prepend the file I want to do something like `$ zip --fix 1.zip --out 2.zip` however, I know running this command in ruby with the `system()` function is not my best option considering I want my code to run on windows (cygwin does not provide a `zip` command. Does anyone know how to emulate the `$ zip --fix` command via ruby.